# working with azure ad documentation Get recent user activities

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

so following this documentation in this part of the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/projectrome-get-recent-activities?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request

the code in the docs returns a 429 Error message: {"Message":"Request limit exceeded for Authentication Failure"}

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

UserActivityRecentCollectionPage recent = graphClient.me().activities()
    .recent()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

I did make sure the permissions are given and other apis do work

I made sure the permission work.
I tried to add parameters like the ones in the docs but I was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors), 429 error will only be reported if your number of requests exceeds the service limit. Since this error is usually thrown in high concurrency scenarios, I can't reproduce it for you.

You can avoid such errors by referring to the [Microsoft Graph service-specific limitations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits)

Hope this helps

Thanks